# Web Service reference error (asp/vb.net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

i'm trying to use a web service on my web application writed on visual studio 2012.

this is my web service:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class WebService1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
       Return "Hello World"
    End Function

End Class
```

web.config configuration:

```
<system.web>

    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx"
        type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory"
         validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>

....

</system.web>
```

decleared on the site.master

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference
            path="../WebService1.asmx" />
        </Services>

.....

</asp:ScriptManager>
```

The call from javascript triggered from a button

```
function provaWebService() {
            alert("entrato")
            WebService1.HelloWorld(onSuccess);
        }

        function onSuccess(result) {
            alert(result)
        }
```

I'm getting this error from firefox console: ReferenceError: WebService1 is not defined

and

ReferenceError: Type is not defined

Some help?

Comment: Sorry, just a note to you - I've deleted my answer as it doesn't seem to be what you're after. Hopefully someone else can assist

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing the namespace. You always need the **fully qualified** name of the class to call the webservice:
http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2007/10/calling-asmx-web-services-directly-from.html

Comment: Well, now i don't get the errors, but i still don't get result from the function in the webservice O.o

Comment: It's strange. If i debug with the console of chrome the script i can see the correct result with an alert or in a div, but after the execution of the script the result disappear

Comment: And with firefox the callback function it's not reached if i debug the scripts <.< with chrome it's reached -.-